# Как получить алфавит определённого языка/локали?

Tags: linux, unix, locale, поиск-программ, utility

Есть ли в линуксе готовые утилиты, с помощью которых можно получить алфавит языка (не только английского)? Типа такого:

```
localeinfo 'ru_RU.UTF-8' | grep 'alphabet'
```

И получить "абвгд...".

Comment: Вас интересуют символы алфавита привязанные к заданной в указанной локали раскладки клавиатуры?